# Помогите решить задачу python

Tags: python, строки

Задача 3. Случайные соревнования

Мы хотим протестировать работу электронной таблицы для участников некоторых соревнований. Есть два списка (то есть две команды), по 20 участников в каждом. В этих списках хранятся очки каждого участника (это вещественные числа с двумя знаками после точки, например 4.03). Участник одной команды соревнуется с участником другой команды под таким же номером. То есть первый соревнуется с первым, второй — со вторым и так далее.

Напишите программу, которая генерирует два списка участников (по 20 элементов) из случайных вещественных чисел (от 5 до 10). Для этого найдите подходящую функцию из модуля random. Затем сгенерируйте третий список, в котором окажутся только победители из каждой пары.

Пример:

Первая команда:

```
[7.86, 6.76, 9.97, 9.08, 5.45, 6.9, 8.65, 5.17, 8.17, 5.06, 7.56, 7.1, 7.18, 8.25, 5.53, 7.95, 8.91, 7.11, 8.29, 9.52]
```

Вторая команда:

```
[7.13, 5.7, 8.89, 5.36, 5.62, 9.46, 5.82, 8.67, 8.41, 7.0, 5.31, 7.8, 9.93, 7.76, 7.4, 8.26, 7.94, 5.71, 7.89, 7.77]
```

Победители тура:

```
[7.86, 6.76, 9.97, 9.08, 5.62, 9.46, 8.65, 8.67, 8.41, 7.0, 7.56, 7.8, 9.93, 8.25, 7.4, 8.26, 8.91, 7.11, 8.29, 9.52]
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: не могу выбрать рандомные числа и сравнить их между собой и записать какая из них пойдет в третий список выйгравших

Comment: 1. [random.uniform(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform); 2. max(m[i], n[i])

Comment: Предоставьте код, где вы пытаетесь решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 2):

*Спасибо*  Jack_oS

```
import random


def main():
    a = [round(random.uniform(5, 10), 2) for i in range(20)]
    b = [round(random.uniform(5, 10), 2) for i in range(20)]
    finall_result = list(map(max, a, b))

    print(f"Первая команда:  {a}")
    print(f"Вторая команда:  {b}")
    print(f"Победители тура: {finall_result}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Для чего нужна конструкция:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Comment: можете объяснить зачем в конце нужно if ?

Comment: Правило хорошего тона)

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Отметьте ответ как правильный, если он вам помог (поставить галочку).

Comment: Ну и стрелочку вверх не забудьте поставить)

Comment: print(f"Результат: {list(finall_result)}")

Comment: В обоих случаях синтаксис правильный, можете объяснить в чём разница?

Comment: да только в синтаксисе, я бы даже так `finall_result = list(map(max, a, b))` и `print(f"Победители тура: {finall_result}")` оставил для читабельности

Comment: Да вы правы так будет лучше.

Answer (score -2):

```
import random

s1 = []
s2 = []
s3 = []

for x in range(20):
    s1.append(round(random.uniform(5,10),2))
    s2.append(round(random.uniform(5,10),2))

    if s1[x] >= s2[x]:
        s3.append(s1[x])
    else:
        s3.append(s2[x])

print(s1)
print(s2)
print(s3)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]